# Best way to alter the property value which is read from the properties files

Tags: spring, string, spring-boot, java-8, application.properties

I have an `application.properties` file as follow

```
mail.content = Hey #name Good morning #name, are you a good developer?
```

My Java Spring boot code

```java
public class MailUtils{
     @Value("${mail.content}")
     String content;
     //Other codes
    
    public void sendMail(){
     //Other code
     String body = content.replaceAll("#name", firstName);
     //reamining code
}
```

I need to alter the value from the application properties based on the java variable. For that, I am using the String class replace method. I just need to know do we have any way better than this? If it is possible, kindly assist me to do that?

Thank you

Comment: I suggest instead of replacing the #name, create multiple properties and then append strings to build your final string.. This will give you flexibility.

Comment: @mahesh, I can not do that since the variable is changed based on user input & the content is big (#name more than 4 times)

Comment: https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Java’s MessageFormat and use that syntax.  Much more powerful and less side effects than a replace all.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html

Use the {} placeholder in your application.properties.

int planet = 7;
String event = "a disturbance in the Force";

```
String result = MessageFormat.format(
     "At {1,time} on {1,date}, there was {2} on planet {0,number,integer}.",
     planet, new Date(), event);
 
The output is:
 At 12:30 PM on Jul 3, 2053, there was a disturbance in the Force on planet 7.
```

Comment: Thanks Brain, Will try

Answer (score 0):

I would change the property at creation of MailUtils. Where is 'firstName' declared?

```
public class MailUtils {

    String content;

    @Value("${mail.content}")
    public void setContent(String content) {
        String firstname = System.getProperty("user.name");
        this.content = content.replace("#name", firstname);
    }

    public void sendMail(){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Bastian but this doesn't seem like a solution for me since this is somehow same as my implemetnation

Comment: Well, then I misundestood your question. Could you clarify the origin of 'firstname' and perhaps the purpose of sendMail ?